# Bitwise or over an array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, bitwise-or

I have a large array of binary numbers, and I want to do a bitwise OR over one dimension of the array:

```
X = [ 192, 96,  96,  2,  3
       12, 12, 128, 49, 14
       ....
    ];
union_of_bits_on_dim2 = [
       bitor(X(:,1), bitor(X(:,2), bitor(X(:,3), ... )))
    ];
ans = 
    [ 227
      191 
      ... ]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? I'm actually working on an n-dimensional array. I tried `bi2de` but it flattens out my array and so the subscripting becomes complicated.

I could do it easily if matlab had a `fold` function but I don't think it does.

---

OK  @Divakar asked for runnable code so to make it clear here is a long-winded version that might work for a 2D array.

```
function U=union_of_bits_on_dim2(X)
U=zeros(size(X,1),1);
for i=1:size(X,2)
  U=bitor(U,X(:,i));
end
```

Surely it be done without looping? I was of course hoping that `bitor` could take arbitrary numbers of arguments. Then it could have been done with `mat2cell`.

Comment: Could you post runnable code to get `union_of_bits_on_dim2`?

Comment: OK have given an example using a loop

Comment: What data types are your numbers? double | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64? Or do you just want the usual binary representation of unsigned integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One vectorized approach -

```
[m,n] =  size(X)  %// Get size of input array
bd = dec2bin(X)-'0' %// Get binary digits

%// Get cumulative "OR-ed" version with ANY(..,1)
cum_or = reshape(any(permute(reshape(bd,m,n,[]),[2 3 1]),1),8,[]) 

%// Finally convert to decimals
U = 2.^(7: -1:0)*cum_or
```

Comment: Thank you this works. But it is more complex than I had hoped! (and even more so with n dimensions)

Comment: @SanjayManohar With those reshapes and permutes I guess it could look that way! But if you get a chance, let us know about any speedups you might be getting with this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any function that can do that automatically. However you can loop over the dimension you are interested in:

```
function result = bitor2d(A)
    result = A(1,:);
    for i=2:size(A,1)
        result = bitor(result,A(i,:));
    end
end
```

If your array has more than 2 dimensions, then you need to prepare it to have only 2.

```
function result = bitornd(A,whichdimension)
    B = shiftdim(A,whichdimension-1); % change dimensions order
    s = size(B);
    B = reshape(B,s(1),[]);  % back to the original shape
    result = bitor2d(B);
    s(1) = 1;
    result = reshape(result,s); % back to the original shape
    result = shiftdim(result,1-whichdimension); % back to the original dimension order
end
```

Comment: Thank you I had not heard of `shiftdim` which is v useful.